# What does the orange text mean in the Party Finder?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Occasionally I'll see a group listed in the Party Finder that stands out because the objective name will be in orange:

[image: Image of Party Finder]

What does this orange signify?

Things I don't think are the case:

1. The blacklist.  These parties show grayed out with strike-through text instead.
2. People on my friends list.  The person hosting the party isn't on my friend's list.  A quick scan of my friends list showed they were all either busy or different classes than the other person in the party.
3. Some kind of Party category. I've seen this listed on parties that don't have any of the "Urgent", "Serious play", etc. tags listed at all.
4. Private parties.  These have a little lock icon next to the player's name.
5. Cross-server parties.  These are denoted by the little flower next to the player's name.

What does this indicator actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange text signifies parties recruiting solely from your server.

I was able to verify this by creating my own party and unchecking the "recruit members across data center" option and seeing my party's name appear in orange.  Recreating my recruitment request with this option checked made the name show up in white.

Hat tip to [Leo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/301350/16953) for giving me the idea to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to locate some in-text/in-game info but I believe that is either indicating a password is needed or that it is a cross server party. If I can find more concrete proof I will re-post, but I believe it is one of those.

Comment: The cross-server party is the little flower icon next to the player names so that's not it.  Not sure on the other one.  I know details for private parties show a tiny lock icon on the join party screen, but my original screenshot just had the listing so I'll have to check again.